# Admin > system settings unavailable after wordpress database import

Tags: admin

Part of my civicrm admin area and front-end forms are missing after import of wordpress database. I can see my contributions dashboard for example, but not the manage contribution pages section or any of the Administer area, so I cannot check systems setting > resource urls, or cleanup cache etc. This means also that my forms are missing on the front end. I have reset my WP database and Civicrm database from a couple of days ago and it hasn't made any difference. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: We can give much more helpful information if you give your CiviCRM version (and the version you upgraded from).  Also, when you say they're "missing", could you please be more specific?  Are the menu items missing?  When you click the menu items, do you get an error?  A white screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers - upvoting your suggestions, all good answers. In my case it turned out that removing the temp files in civicrm/templates_c/en_US allowed those forms and backend areas to be rebuilt, so it was permissions in those files.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - could you have done a 'clean cache' or did you try that?

Comment: That was one of the areas that was unavailable to me, everything under the Administer menu was not there. All of that area as well as, for example, the contributions dashboard and my front-end forms rebuilt when I removed those temp files. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a permissions problem. Make sure you are logged in as a user who has full "administer CiviCRM" permissions in Wordpress.

Comment: Indeed - after re-reading this and seeing the problem happened after you imported your Wordpress database, and you seem to be indicating that it's separate from your Civi database, this is almost certainly a permissions issue.  CiviCRM stores its permissions in the host CMS' native format, so I suspect you need to re-set your permissions.

Comment: Any idea what files I should be checking permissions on? To answer your earlier question, I'm not getting any errors, the menu items are there but when I select one I just get the title and otherwise the page is empty. Likewise on the front-end, I get no errors, just a grey box where my form should be but none of the fields. Thanks.

Comment: Your user ACL permissions (Admin>Users & Permissions>Access Control)- when you log in as an admin from WP.  You can also 'sync users' in case your WP database import file had/has a different email address for you - check your Contact record in Civi

Answer (score 1):

not files, your user ACL permissions (Admin>Users & Permissions>Access Control)- when you log in as an admin from WP. You can also 'sync users' in case your WP database import file had/has a different email address for you - check your Contact record in Civi - or create a new WP login for yourself as Admin and check